# Why are arguments of a command altered when viewed by ps?

Tags: shell, command-line, ps

When I run my favorite app, why the arguments look different when viewed by `ps`?

```
$ redshift -l 12.94:43.75 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
[1] 8637
$ ps -o cmd= -C redshift
redshift -l 12.94 43.75
```

Notice the missing colon.

Comment: a process is able to modify its parameters at run-time; that may be what `redshift` is doing.

Comment: @JeffSchaller how could I do that in C?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169987/update-process-name-in-shell-is-it-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the details are operating-system specific, most systems allow you to alter the command-line arguments as they are reported by ps (or in the /proc file system).  For example, on some systems you can directly edit argv.

Many systems ship with a library function called setproctitle that allows you to do this.  So a good place to look would be the man page and source to setproctitle if you want to see how this works on your system.